# Convert output array stream to json format which acts an input to the another module

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, data-structures

As per my task, I need to the output array which returns a 17x2 matrix. Sample output is shown below,

```
[[[112.7389984  435.22939381]
  [105.58624109 442.22496105]
  [105.40821313 428.48843217]
  [111.54160163 455.5956664 ]
  [111.73701629 422.6852232 ]
  [157.57940773 468.98824122]
  [152.69650377 418.14950772]
  [216.09577598 494.46142991]
  [216.24983383 398.55651579]
  [187.72555422 470.64766974]
  [195.02623991 401.41814955]
  [250.42257518 456.73815289]
  [254.02587076 414.79482611]
  [342.11166065 465.78956559]
  [337.49021309 398.70648202]
  [420.26860336 483.16769808]
  [413.13895387 400.20868124]]
```

This output has to be updated and rearranged into a json format which acts as a input to another module. The sample `json` file looks as follows

```
"people": [{"pose_keypoints_2d": [373.66941223936897, 154.11017137748198, 376.56976806799094, 148.62508032371454, 380.12147964285106, 146.7658045737609, 408.1720184452102, 150.81495177498203, 395.4577760498318, 148.65305484579298, 429.2950931571711, 187.23194235510218, 427.43709937755006, 183.81666234409775, 438.86293520488795, 242.28969041954517, 406.0761933264817, 239.55742403024738, 391.300993933522, 275.09581687542385, 366.366300313692, 273.31374397263687, 437.8343750984803, 266.7701811748018, 413.9231729479147, 269.37950168236074, 427.40363975660733, 334.6826900855724, 391.21232291711186, 334.43577344764236, 471.9465081925208, 373.23237206886364, 393.9988229904401, 372.1616302399678, 0.0, 0.0]}]}
```

Basically the structure should be of the order

```
"people": [{"pose_keypoints_2d": [x0,y0,x1,y1, x35,y35 ]}]}
```

For the array I could create something like

```
dc = {"people":[]}
    flat = [0.0 for i in range(36)]
```

which is basically a 1D vector. I am trying to fill in the vector, serially (x0,y0,x1,y1... ). I think in matlab one had inbuilt commands to do that. I was looking into the command `enumerate` but i am not sure if that's the way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some playground: Run, update and see what you can do:

```
import numpy as np
import json
#Creating 17x2 matrix
my_matrix = np.random.rand(17,2)
print(my_matrix)
print(my_matrix.shape)
print("------------------------------")
#Creating output format (Creating dictionary)
my_dict = {}
new_dict = {}
my_dict["pose_keypoints_2d"] = my_matrix
new_dict['people'] = my_dict
print(new_dict)
print("------------------------------")
# Creating json
json_data = json.dumps(new_dict['people']["pose_keypoints_2d"].tolist())
print(type(json_data))
print(json_data)
print("------------------------------")

#Now reverse, json to numpy array matrix
data = json.loads(json_data)
numpy_matrix = np.reshape(data,(17,2))
print(numpy_matrix)
```

Comment: i think i have to understand how dictionary works, i seem to come up with an error with vaiablee my_dict is not defined . but thanks for the heads up

Comment: @BasicVisual now try running above code. I have updated for that error message.

Comment: thanks !! i tired initializing both  my_dict  but i wonder why i got the error . Thanks a lot ! i will nevertheless look into dictionary

Comment: The above code working for me on Python3 - Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Thank you for helping me to visualize how each output looks like . I actually tried to initialize , the variable  'dict' with 1 Dimensional vector of zeros using  'numbpy'  command . `my_dict =  np.zeros((36,), dtype=int)`, i wanted in the final output , to be padded with zeros in the end . I noted the output of `new_dict` which is what we are aiming for . Is there a way to manipulate to exclude `[]` and ` array ` and pad in the end with zeros. Trying to have the same format as  `"people": [{"pose_keypoints_2d": [x0,y0,x1,y1, x33,y33,0,0]}]}` ` I have to look into the `json dump ` command

Comment: you can re-shape linearly defined 1D array of zeros or ones or random numbers anyways. To serialize the values in json use list of your elements and when you want them on numpy, simply convert them into list and then re-shape using numpy that will give you numpy array.

Comment: thanks , if i understand correctly , re-shape of numpy you are refering to array of zeros right  ? and y serializing you mean to , manipulate the output dict_new ? Sorry beginner here , so its hard to comprehend sometimes

Comment: yes, make the first 10 as list, so list of 17*2 matrix and fetch each matrix based iterating through 10 items. but can you post sample data using a link or some kind a way.

Comment: Thanks i managed to that, i was curious how i could output the json file. I saw `filewrite` i know i can create with `os` create directories but how can i output , for example to json file named `capture.json` under the `capture` folder. `json.dump` seem to have a outfile option. Or do i have to do it manually ?

Comment: either way, using library to create json file directly or simply create `yourfile.json` file and then open it and write into that file.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Define your dict accordingly, then iterate through your matrix via list comprehension

```
dct  = {'people':[{"pose_keypoints_2d": []}]}
dct['people'][0]["pose_keypoints_2d"] = [val[0] for val in matrix[0]]
print(dct)
#{'people': [{'pose_keypoints_2d': [112.7389984, 105.58624109,  
#   105.40821313, #111.54160163, 111.73701629, 157.57940773,  
#152.69650377,   216.09577598, #216.24983383, 187.72555422, 195.02623991,  
#250.42257518,  254.02587076, #342.11166065, 337.49021309, 420.26860336,  
 #413.13895387]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks , just to understand what you mean by iteration ? Do i have to iterate over the whole 17x2 matrix ?

Comment: Iteration is just running a for loop over your matrix, yes you need to iterate over your entire matrix since you want 1D vector